# Ruby - trying to make hashtags within string into links

Tags: ruby, regex, iteration, hashtag

I am trying to make the hashtags within a string into links.

e.g. I'd like a string that's currently: "I'm a string which contains a #hashtag" to transform into: "I'm a string which contains [#hashtag](/%23hashtag)"

The code that I have at the moment is as follows:

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
    <% string = message.content %>
    <% hashtaglinks = string.scan(/#(\d*)/).flatten %>
    <% hashtaglinks.each do |tag| %>
            <li><%= string = string.gsub(/##{tag}\b/, link_to("google", "##{tag}") %><li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've been trying (in vain) for several hours to get this to work, reading through many similar stackoverflow threads- but frustration has got the better of me, and as a beginner rubyist, I'd be really appreciate it if someone could please help me out!

The code in my 'server.rb' is as follows:

```
get '/' do
    @messages = Message.all
    erb :index
end

post '/messages' do
    content = params["content"]
    hashtags = params["content"].scan(/#\w+/).flatten.map{|hashtag| 
Hashtag.first_or_create(:text => hashtag)}
    Message.create(:content => content, :hashtags => hashtags)
    redirect to('/')
end

get '/hashtags/:text' do
    hashtag = Hashtag.first(:text => params[:text])
    @messages = hashtag ? hashtag.messages : []
    erb :index
end

helpers do

def link_to(url,text=url,opts={})
  attributes = ""
  opts.each { |key,value| attributes << key.to_s << "=\"" << value << "\" "}
  "<a href=\"#{url}\" #{attributes}>#{text}</a>"
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to get you started. This should replace (in-place) the hashtags in the `string` with the links:

```
<% string.gsub!(/#\w+/) do |tag| %>
  <% link_to("##{tag}", url_you_want_to_replace_hashtag_with) %>
<% end %>
```

You may need to use `html_safe` on the string to display it afterwards.

The regex doesn't account for more complex cases, like what do you do in case of `##tag0` or `#tag1#tag2`. Should `tag0` and `tag2` be considered hashtags? Also, you may want to change `\w` to something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if you want to limit the tags to alphanumerics and digits only.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Hours of frustration finally relieved.